# What form is a Waltz in?

Tags: theory, piano, notation, technique, sheet-music

What form is a waltz in? I've heard lots of things coming from lots of people but it is not very clear. I need it for a music theory study.

Comment: Aside from being in 3/4 time, there is no single "waltz form", though various composers have had their own characteristic styles. Perhaps you could list a few of the things you've heard, or be more specific about how this question fits into your study. That might help get the answers you're looking for.